# how to create web service from existing web dynamic application

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, servlets, jax-ws

My problem is as follows: I have a web dynamic project (Java EE) with 2 classes and a servlet.

The servlet contains a method `sendImage` with 2 parameters (`String` and `HttpServletResponse`), and this method returns the result which I want to use in the response, as a `servletOutputStream`.

I'm trying to use this project to create a stand alone web service (with `JAX-WS`), which I can call from an other web application.

Does anyone have an idea how I should do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout the JAX-WS documentation, or search the internet for a JAX-WS tutorial?

Comment: i already did that, and i can't find an answer. that's why i'm askin here :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JAX-WS. Create a new web-service annotated class. Move the method that you want to convert it to a web service method from your servlet to the web-service class. It seems you want to save an image  in that method so POST method will be a good choice for your web service method. Rest you can find in any JAX-WS tutorial.
Good luck!

Comment: should the new class extend httpServlet ??

Comment: No it need not to. When you use any of the web services framework, they provide you one servlet, which need to be configured in web.xml. That servlet accepts all the incoming HTTP request and then depending on the URL of the request, it will look for Class & Method path mapping in all the classes annotated as Web Service class. Wherever a match is found that method is called and parameters are passed to the method. Parameters can be path or form params. You need to find out what parameters you need and how do you need.